# How do I use the new MediaCodec getInputBuffer(int index)

Tags: android, mp3, android-mediaplayer, android-mediacodec, audiotrack

I have an example that I am working from for decoding mp3 audio with MediaCodec for playing using MediaPlayer and AudioTrack. The example is using getInputBuffers() which is now depricated in API 21+. The new getInputBuffer(int index) returns one buffer instead of an array and the API reference for the MediaCodec still shows the use case for getInputBuffers().

Can anyone explain how I need to go about using the new method? Do I just get the index 0 each time? I started to loop and get each and make an array but there isn't a place, that I have seen, where I can get the length of available buffers.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You shouldn't try to fetch all the buffers.

Prior to API 21, you'd do `ByteBuffer inputs[] = codec.getInputBuffers()`. Then `index = codec.dequeueInputBuffer()` would return a buffer index, and you'd use `inputs[index]`, and finally submit the buffer with `codec.queueInputBuffer(index, ...)`.

Notice that you never touch more than one element in `inputs[]` at a time, and you're only allowed to touch that element between the `dequeueInputBuffer` and `queueInputBuffer` calls.

Now instead of having an array of `ByteBuffer` objects, where you only use one at a time, you're now supposed to fetch only the single `ByteBuffer` you are going to fill. That is, after `index = codec.dequeueInputBuffer()`, instead of using `inputs[index]`, call `codec.getInputBuffer(index)`.

So basically, the array that you used to get returned from `getInputBuffers()` still exists internally within the `MediaCodec` object, but you don't need to keep the full array available, only fetch the single buffer you're going to use each time.